# QChartView and QScatterSeries overrdide the label of a QPointF

Tags: c++, qt5, qchart, qchartview

I have a QChartView which displays some 2D points which are representing each one a specific project I want to label each point with the project name AND NOT with it's x,y coordinates as the default behaviour
[image]

Is there any way to achieve override the function that creates or render the labels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why this could be difficult to achieve without changing the Qt source code**

1. [QXYSeries::setPointLabelsFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qxyseries.html#pointLabelsFormat-prop) wouldn't be of much help to you. It does indeed allow you to change the format of the labels, but the only variable part of it are the coordinates of the points.
2. All the drawing is done in the private part of the Qt classes. Here is the whole story:

The labels are drawn in the [private part](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/xychart/qxyseries.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts16QXYSeriesPrivate21drawSeriesPointLabelsEP8QPainterRK7QVectorI7QPointFEi) of *QXYSeries* (`painter->drawText(position, pointLabel);`):

```
void QXYSeriesPrivate::drawSeriesPointLabels(QPainter *painter, const QVector<QPointF> &points,
                                             const int offset)
{
    if (points.size() == 0)
        return;
    static const QString xPointTag(QLatin1String("@xPoint"));
    static const QString yPointTag(QLatin1String("@yPoint"));
    const int labelOffset = offset + 2;
    painter->setFont(m_pointLabelsFont);
    painter->setPen(QPen(m_pointLabelsColor));
    QFontMetrics fm(painter->font());
    // m_points is used for the label here as it has the series point information
    // points variable passed is used for positioning because it has the coordinates
    const int pointCount = qMin(points.size(), m_points.size());
    for (int i(0); i < pointCount; i++) {
        QString pointLabel = m_pointLabelsFormat;
        pointLabel.replace(xPointTag, presenter()->numberToString(m_points.at(i).x()));
        pointLabel.replace(yPointTag, presenter()->numberToString(m_points.at(i).y()));
        // Position text in relation to the point
        int pointLabelWidth = fm.width(pointLabel);
        QPointF position(points.at(i));
        position.setX(position.x() - pointLabelWidth / 2);
        position.setY(position.y() - labelOffset);
        painter->drawText(position, pointLabel);
    }
}
```

*drawSeriesPointLabels* is called from the [paint method](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/scatterchart/scatterchartitem.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts16ScatterChartItem5paintEP8QPainterPK24QStyleOptionGraphicsItemP7QWidget) of *ScatterChartItem* (this class is not included in the official documentation):

```
void ScatterChartItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(option)
    Q_UNUSED(widget)
    if (m_series->useOpenGL())
        return;
    QRectF clipRect = QRectF(QPointF(0, 0), domain()->size());
    painter->save();
    painter->setClipRect(clipRect);
    if (m_pointLabelsVisible) {
        if (m_pointLabelsClipping)
            painter->setClipping(true);
        else
            painter->setClipping(false);
        m_series->d_func()->drawSeriesPointLabels(painter, m_points,
                                                  m_series->markerSize() / 2
                                                  + m_series->pen().width());
    }
    painter->restore();
}
```

The *ScatterChartItem* in turn is created in the [private part](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/scatterchart/qscatterseries.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts21QScatterSeriesPrivate18initializeGraphicsEP13QGraphicsItem) of *QScatterSeries* and can't be substituted with a custom class:

```
void QScatterSeriesPrivate::initializeGraphics(QGraphicsItem* parent)
{
    Q_Q(QScatterSeries);
    ScatterChartItem *scatter = new ScatterChartItem(q,parent);
    m_item.reset(scatter);
    QAbstractSeriesPrivate::initializeGraphics(parent);
}
```

**What you might wanna try**

1. Hide the original labels with `setPointLabelsVisible(false);` The labels will be drawn separately afterwards.
2. Subclass *QChartView* and reimplement the `paintEvent`, invoking first `QChartView::paintEvent` and then calling a custom function (lets say `drawCustomLabels`), which is a modified version of `QXYSeriesPrivate::drawSeriesPointLabels`. By calling `drawCustomLabels` pass:

   - a local painter drawing on the vieport of *MyChartView*,
   - the points as returned by `QXYSeries::points`,
   - the desired offset.

Here is an example of how the `drawCustomLabels` might look like:

```
void MyChartView::drawCustomLabels(QPainter *painter, const QVector<QPointF> &points, const int offset)
{
    if (points.count() == 0)
        return;

    QFontMetrics fm(painter->font());
    const int labelOffset = offset + 2;

    painter->setFont(m_pointLabelsFont); // Use QXYSeries::pointLabelsFont() to access m_pointLabelsFont
    painter->setPen(QPen(m_pointLabelsColor)); // Use QXYSeries::pointLabelsColor() to access m_pointLabelsColor

    for (int n(0); n < points.count(); n++) {
        QString pointLabel = "..."; // Set the desired label for the n-th point of the series
        // Position text in relation to the point
        int pointLabelWidth = fm.width(pointLabel);
        QPointF position(points.at(n));
        position.setX(position.x() - pointLabelWidth / 2);
        position.setY(position.y() - labelOffset);
        painter->drawText(position, pointLabel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post I have investigate QXYSeriesPrivate::drawSeriesPointLabels already. Is there any option to implement a draw layer above the existing one (without the labels) and render whatever I want to render as text?

Comment: You  are inside my mind that was what I am thinking of... I shall give it a try...

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't manage to map right the coordinates of my points with those of the chartview so I implemented with hovered signal the user have to hover to see the label of the point